# Given a non-singular curve $C$, show that two divisors are algebraically equivalent iff they have the same degree

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I wish to show that given a non-singular curve $C$, two divisors are algebraically equivalent if and only if they have the same degree.

I'm rather stuck on how to approach such a problem. I'm working from Shafarevich, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers; I hope they help.

For the 'only if' part:

1. Show that algebraic equivalence $\sim_a$ is preserved under addition: that is, if $D \sim_a D'$ and $E \sim_a E'$, then $D+E \sim_a D'+E'$ also.
2. Show that if $p$ and $q$ are any two points on your curve, then $p \sim_a q$ as divisors. (Use the diagonal $\Delta \subset C \times C$.)

Combining these statements gives the result.

For the 'if" part: I must admit I don't know all the details off the top of my head. Essentially this will follow from the fact that for a finite map of curves $X \rightarrow Y$ of degree $d$, the pullback (in the sense of divisors) of any point in $Y$ is a divisor of degreee $d$ in $X$; in particular it is the same for all points in $Y$.